# Why did I have a random Frost Troll attack in town?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was waiting in Dawnstar to allow the Khajiit merchant's gold to reset. When it stopped, half the town was dead and a random Frost Troll had appeared. Dawnstar no longer has a blacksmith, nor do the mines have owners.

Does anyone know why this has happened?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably just the AI being AI.

There is a spawn point for frost trolls right next to the town of Dawnstar on the other side of the hill near the road that leads into town. If you stand on top of the hill you should be able to see the trolls easily. There are also different types of creatures that spawn in the area that the troll would try to attack. Chances are while you were waiting for the Khajiit merchants to reset the troll followed the creature AI up towards the town close enough to start locking on to the people in the town.

If you are wondering if there is some kind of scripted event for a troll attack on the town, the answer as it currently stands is No. This is just some of the randomness that comes along with the world of Skyrim.

Comment: So dawnstar no longer has a blacksmith permanently... great

Comment: That depends actually.. Someone will usually step up and take over the job after some time passes but this does not always happen.. It is possible that you may indeed be out a blacksmith if you can not find an older save to revert to.

Comment: I've moved on from the area, i have little to no real reason to go back. How long does it usually take?

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there is a mod that would have helped against this. Would "I Yield! I Yield!" by mrzues68, help?

Comment: @NiteCyper: There are several different mods that attach the "protected" flag to ~all NPCs, which is by far the most thorough way of preventing accidental deaths by any source.